# Blank insertion of collect package destroys indexing

Tags: indexing

Let us start with a minimal working example which illustrates my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex 

\definecollection{test}

\makeatletter
 \newenvironment{testenv}[1]
  {\@nameuse{collect}{#1}{%
    \par%
    {\noindent Test}\par\noindent
    }{
    \par
    }
  }%
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
 \makeatother

\begin{document}
 Text
 \begin{testenv}{test}
  test \index{testindex}
 \end{testenv}

 \newpage
 \includecollection{test}
 \newpage

 \printindex
\end{document}
```

The produced document should now consist of a first page with "Text" on it, the second page contains "Test" and afterwards "test", and the last page contains the index with only "testindex" referring to page 2. However the second page also contains the word "testindex" and the index page contains only an empty string referring to page 2.

The collect page constructs a file `\jobname.test` (due to `\definecollection{test}`) in which the collected content is in. The content of this file is

```
\par {\noindent Test}\par \noindent 
 test \index {testindex}
 \par
```

Here one can see exactly my problem: the blank between `\index` and `{testindex}`. Therefore it seems that the index package thinks of a call `\index{}` due to this.

Is there anyone having an idea how to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a problem when a space follows `\index`, because this command *doesn't* look for an argument, but rather does some adjustments and then calls `\@wrindex`. When `\@wrindex` is called, the space is not a real space any more, but a character with category code 12, so it's not ignored when following a macro name.

This happens because TeX “sees” the space, so it knows a control sequence name has ended, but still has not tokenized nor ignored it. The macro is expanded and chaos ensues. `:-(`

Here's a way to solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex 

\makeatletter
\let\ori@wrindex\@wrindex
\def\@wrindex{%
  \@ifnextchar\bgroup\ori@wrindex{\expandafter\ori@wrindex\@gobble}%
}
\makeatother


\definecollection{test}

\newenvironment{testenv}[1]
  {\collect{#1}{%
    \par%
    {\noindent Test}\par\noindent
    }{
    \par
    }
  }%
 {\endcollect}

\begin{document}
 Text
 \begin{testenv}{test}
  test \index{testindex}
 \end{testenv}

 \newpage
 \includecollection{test}
 \newpage

 \printindex
\end{document}
```

If `\index` is followed by a brace, the original command is immediately executed, otherwise a token is consumed (which is the space when the `\index` command is in a collected file).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have currently a quite large document and it seems it is slowed down by \tracingmacros=1 up to the point that pdflatexmk does not run through. After I removed the \tracingmacros=1 it compiles very fast as before. Still everything works. Can you explain the sense of the command? It seems that it is not necessary and causes problems for me.

Comment: @Arne Sorry, I added `\tracingcommands=1` for debugging and forgot to remove it in the final version.